# How to embed fonts within a ConTeXt document?

Tags: fonts, pdf, context, context-mkiv, embedding

I wrote a book using ConTeXt. I used a typescript to define the fonts. When compiled and viewed on my computer, the fonts appeared correctly. I sent my book to a printing place to have them print the PDF file. When I got the printed book, all of the fonts were changed to a different font.

- Does ConTeXt embed fonts within the PDF files?
- If not, is there some command for asking ConTeXt to do so?

Comment: Look in Properties in your PDF viewer to see if they are embedded. Or use `pdffonts` (at least on GNU/Linux) at the command line. If you convert the file to postscript using Ghostscript and then back to PDF, your file will be very large but it will avoid the problem of substituted fonts. (Basically, all fonts will be converted to images.)

Comment: How do you compile your ConTeXt documents? Typically, if you are using `luatex` or `pdftex` engines (i.e., you use `context filename` or `texexec filename`), then ConTeXt embeds the fonts. If you are first generating a dvi file (using `texexec --dvi filename`) or if you are using `xetex` (`texexec --xetex filename`), then embedding for fonts depends on the preference for `dvips` program.

Comment: I checked in Adobe Reader, File-->Properties-->Fonts, and it says "embedded subset", so I assume that means all of the letters used in the document were embedded. I'm using `context filename` to compile.

Comment: Demand your money back from the printer and use another service. They probably can not handle PDFs correctly. At the very least they should have preflighted the PDF and alerted you of any problems.

Comment: Also, what kind of printing service doesn't give you electronic proofs for your book before physically printing it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a printing issue.